# Turning on hot spot on iPhone causes my app's screen shift downwards

Tags: iphone, ios

When I turn on personnel HOT SPOT in my iPhone then my app's screen moves downwards in which I am loading sub views. But on other screens it doesn't takes place. It happens only on screen in which I am loading subviews. So can anybody tell me what can be the problem ? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

whenever the hotspot or other notification appears the statusBarFrame will become 40px high.

```
CGRect rect;
rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]; // Get screen dimensions
NSLog(@"Bounds: %1.0f, %1.0f, %1.0f, %1.0f", rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);

rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]; // Get application frame dimensions (basically screen - status bar)
NSLog(@"App Frame: %1.0f, %1.0f, %1.0f, %1.0f", rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);

rect = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame]; // Get status bar frame dimensions
NSLog(@"Statusbar frame: %1.0f, %1.0f, %1.0f, %1.0f", rect.origin.x, rect.origin.y, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
```

Comment: Hi Amit thanks for your reply, can you tell me if I can restrict status bar to original size even when HOT SPOT is on.

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the `UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification` and `UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification` notifications which will tell you the new size of the status bar. Avoid hard coding anything (e.g. 40pt) and instead get the new status bar frame from the notification.

If you just need the height, you can pull that out easily. If you need to do anything more complicated with the status bar frame, you'll have to convert it from screen coordinates to your own view's coordinate system (e.g. if you have a full screen layout view controller and need to lay things out underneath it):

```
- (void)statusBarFrameWillChangeNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSValue *rectValue = notification.userInfo[UIApplicationStatusBarFrameUserInfoKey];

    CGRect statusBarFrame = [rectValue CGRectValue];

    // if you just need the height, you can stop here

    // otherwise convert the frame to our view's coordinate system
    UIWindow *targetWindow = self.view.window;
    // fromWindow:nil here converts from screen coordinates to the window
    CGRect statusBarFrameWindowCoords = [targetWindow convertRect:statusBarFrame
                                                       fromWindow:nil];
    CGRect frameRelativeToOurView = [self.view convertRect:statusBarFrameWindowCoords
                                                  fromView:targetWindow];

    // ...
}
```

Converting the coordinates is going to be especially important in iOS 7 where all view controllers have full screen layout by default.

Answer (score 0):

The status bar expands and becomes 20 pixels bigger, the position of the status bar does not change, only the size. There is no bool I think, however you can just check if

```
statusbarframe.size.height>20
```